# Parsing with MaltParser engmalt

Tags: java, text-parsing

I'm trying to use the pretrained parsing model [engmalt](http://maltparser.org/mco/english_parser/engmalt.html). I downloaded it, I unpacked it in the directory where I downloaded the MaltParser, and I wrote in the prompt

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar malt.jar -c engmalt.poly -i infile.conll -o outfile.conll -m parse
```

as suggested in MalParser site. The problem is that it gives me this error:

> the file entry "engmaltpoly_single.info" in the mco file "../malt-1.4.1/engmaltpoly.mco" cannot be found.

Can someone help me? 
I'm working with Windows7 and jre6. How can I pack the folder downloaded from the site(engmalt.poly) in a file .mco?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not suppose to add any extension to model file name. So give a try as:

"java -Xmx1024m -jar malt.jar -c engmalt -i infile.conll -o outfile.conll -m parse"