# Parsing multiple sentences with MaltParser using NLTK

Tags: java, python, parsing, nlp, nltk

There have been many MaltParser and/or NLTK related questions:

- [Malt Parser throwing class not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091698/malt-parser-throwing-class-not-found-exception)
- [How to use malt parser in python nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009330/how-to-use-malt-parser-in-python-nltk)
- [MaltParser Not Working in Python NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513187/maltparser-not-working-in-python-nltk)
- [NLTK MaltParser won't parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524553/nltk-maltparser-wont-parse)
- [Dependency parser using NLTK and MaltParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815891/dependency-parser-using-nltk-and-maltparser)
- [Dependency Parsing using MaltParser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463519/dependency-parsing-using-maltparser-and-nltk)
- [Parsing with MaltParser engmalt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944269/parsing-with-maltparser-engmalt)
- [Parse raw text with MaltParser in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392790/parse-raw-text-with-maltparser-in-java)

Now, there's a more stabilized version of MaltParser API in NLTK: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/944 but there are issues when it comes to parsing multiple sentences at the same time.

Parsing one sentence at a time seems fine:

```
_path_to_maltparser = '/home/alvas/maltparser-1.8/dist/maltparser-1.8/'
_path_to_model= '/home/alvas/engmalt.linear-1.7.mco'     
>>> mp = MaltParser(path_to_maltparser=_path_to_maltparser, model=_path_to_model)
>>> sent = 'I shot an elephant in my pajamas'.split()
>>> sent2 = 'Time flies like banana'.split()
>>> print(mp.parse_one(sent).tree())
(pajamas (shot I) an elephant in my)
```

But parsing a list of sentences doesn't return a DependencyGraph object:

```
_path_to_maltparser = '/home/alvas/maltparser-1.8/dist/maltparser-1.8/'
_path_to_model= '/home/alvas/engmalt.linear-1.7.mco'     
>>> mp = MaltParser(path_to_maltparser=_path_to_maltparser, model=_path_to_model)
>>> sent = 'I shot an elephant in my pajamas'.split()
>>> sent2 = 'Time flies like banana'.split()
>>> print(mp.parse_one(sent).tree())
(pajamas (shot I) an elephant in my)
>>> print(next(mp.parse_sents([sent,sent2])))
<listiterator object at 0x7f0a2e4d3d90> 
>>> print(next(next(mp.parse_sents([sent,sent2]))))
[{u'address': 0,
  u'ctag': u'TOP',
  u'deps': [2],
  u'feats': None,
  u'lemma': None,
  u'rel': u'TOP',
  u'tag': u'TOP',
  u'word': None},
 {u'address': 1,
  u'ctag': u'NN',
  u'deps': [],
  u'feats': u'_',
  u'head': 2,
  u'lemma': u'_',
  u'rel': u'nn',
  u'tag': u'NN',
  u'word': u'I'},
 {u'address': 2,
  u'ctag': u'NN',
  u'deps': [1, 11],
  u'feats': u'_',
  u'head': 0,
  u'lemma': u'_',
  u'rel': u'null',
  u'tag': u'NN',
  u'word': u'shot'},
 {u'address': 3,
  u'ctag': u'AT',
  u'deps': [],
  u'feats': u'_',
  u'head': 11,
  u'lemma': u'_',
  u'rel': u'nn',
  u'tag': u'AT',
  u'word': u'an'},
 {u'address': 4,
  u'ctag': u'NN',
  u'deps': [],
  u'feats': u'_',
  u'head': 11,
  u'lemma': u'_',
  u'rel': u'nn',
  u'tag': u'NN',
  u'word': u'elephant'},
 {u'address': 5,
  u'ctag': u'NN',
  u'deps': [],
  u'feats': u'_',
  u'head': 11,
  u'lemma': u'_',
  u'rel': u'nn',
  u'tag': u'NN',
  u'word': u'in'},
 {u'address': 6,
  u'ctag': u'NN',
  u'deps': [],
  u'feats': u'_',
  u'head': 11,
  u'lemma': u'_',
  u'rel': u'nn',
  u'tag': u'NN',
  u'word': u'my'},
 {u'address': 7,
  u'ctag': u'NNS',
  u'deps': [],
  u'feats': u'_',
  u'head': 11,
  u'lemma': u'_',
  u'rel': u'nn',
  u'tag': u'NNS',
  u'word': u'pajamas'},
 {u'address': 8,
  u'ctag': u'NN',
  u'deps': [],
  u'feats': u'_',
  u'head': 11,
  u'lemma': u'_',
  u'rel': u'nn',
  u'tag': u'NN',
  u'word': u'Time'},
 {u'address': 9,
  u'ctag': u'NNS',
  u'deps': [],
  u'feats': u'_',
  u'head': 11,
  u'lemma': u'_',
  u'rel': u'nn',
  u'tag': u'NNS',
  u'word': u'flies'},
 {u'address': 10,
  u'ctag': u'NN',
  u'deps': [],
  u'feats': u'_',
  u'head': 11,
  u'lemma': u'_',
  u'rel': u'nn',
  u'tag': u'NN',
  u'word': u'like'},
 {u'address': 11,
  u'ctag': u'NN',
  u'deps': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  u'feats': u'_',
  u'head': 2,
  u'lemma': u'_',
  u'rel': u'dep',
  u'tag': u'NN',
  u'word': u'banana'}]
```

**Why is that using `parse_sents()` don't return an iterable of `parse_one`?**

I could however, just get lazy and do:

```
_path_to_maltparser = '/home/alvas/maltparser-1.8/dist/maltparser-1.8/'
_path_to_model= '/home/alvas/engmalt.linear-1.7.mco'     
>>> mp = MaltParser(path_to_maltparser=_path_to_maltparser, model=_path_to_model)
>>> sent1 = 'I shot an elephant in my pajamas'.split()
>>> sent2 = 'Time flies like banana'.split()
>>> sentences = [sent1, sent2]
>>> for sent in sentences:
>>> ...    print(mp.parse_one(sent).tree())
```

But this is not the solution I'm looking for. **My question is how to answer why doesn't the `parse_sent()` return an iterable of `parse_one()`. and how could it be fixed in the NLTK code?**

---

After @NikitaAstrakhantsev answered, I've tried it outputs a parse tree now but it seems to be confused and puts both sentences into one before parsing it.

```
# Initialize a MaltParser object with a pre-trained model.
mp = MaltParser(path_to_maltparser=path_to_maltparser, model=path_to_model) 
sent = 'I shot an elephant in my pajamas'.split()
sent2 = 'Time flies like banana'.split()
# Parse a single sentence.
print(mp.parse_one(sent).tree())
print(next(next(mp.parse_sents([sent,sent2]))).tree())
```

[out]:

```
(pajamas (shot I) an elephant in my)
(shot I (banana an elephant in my pajamas Time flies like))
```

From the code it seems to be doing something weird: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/api.py#L45

**Why is it that the parser abstract class in NLTK is swooshing two sentences into one before parsing? Am I calling the `parse_sents()` incorrectly? If so, what is the correct way to call `parse_sents()`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see in your code samples, you don't call `tree()` in this line

```
>>> print(next(next(mp.parse_sents([sent,sent2]))))
```

while you do call `tree()` in all cases with `parse_one()`.

Otherwise I don't see the reason why it could happen: `parse_one()` method of `ParserI` isn't overridden in `MaltParser` and everything it does is simply calling `parse_sents()` of `MaltParser`, see [the code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/api.py).

**Upd:** [The line you're talking about](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/api.py#L45) isn't called, because `parse_sents()` is overridden in `MaltParser` and is directly called.

The only guess I have now is that java lib maltparser doesn't work correctly with input file containing several sentences (I mean [this block](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/malt.py#L149) - where java is run). Maybe original malt parser has changed the format and now it is not `'\n\n'`. 
Unfortunately, I can't run this code by myself, because [maltparser.org](http://maltparser.org/) is down for the second day. I checked that the input file has expected format (sentences are separated by double endline), so it is very unlikely that python wrapper merges sentences.

Comment: Thank you!! Now it outputs the tree but it's a wrong tree, see updated question.

Comment: Found the bug!!! I'm sooo blind https://github.com/alvations/nltk/blob/patch-1/nltk/parse/malt.py#L56 the `yield '\n\n'` was in the wrong indent!!! gosh...